# DDD Repo - repo.findByChildId(id) AND repo.transferChild(to, from, child)

Tags: service, repository, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I've recently started looking into DDD and have been refactoring an old personal project to this pattern. I'm about halfway through Evans blue book, and can't seem to find the answer for this there or online anywhere.

Basically my application is an inventory tracker. Inventory would contain a collection of items, items are transferrable entities between inventories. Inventory would have methods like `transferIn() transferOut()` which would contain some validation logic, ie checking that the inventory is not already full or that the item is in a transferrable state. These constraints lead me to believe that inventory is the aggregate root and that item is an entity.

1) at some point if a user requests a specific item entity for their inventory I would like to have a `inventoryRepo.findByItemId(id)` which would return the inventory that currently has that item. So that I can:

2) through a service do something like:

```
boolean requestItemTransfer(destInvId, itemId){
    Inv from = invRepo.findByItemId(itemId);
    Inv to = invRepo.findById(destInvId);
    from.transferOut(itemId);
    to.transferIn(from.getItem(itemId));
    return invRepo.transferChild(to, item); //Edited
}
```

Basically writing my validation logic in the inventory class (rich domain model) and if there are no exceptions then I use the repo.transfer() method to persist the changes.

**Would I be violating DDD? Are there better alternatives?**

From what I've read and understood this seems valid if only unconventional. Every example that I've found shows entities that can only exist within 1 root instance. There's also the bank account transfer examples but those deal with amounts that are value objects, and have a transfer repository because transfers are to be recorded in that particular scenario, just not in mine.

**EDIT:**
The use cases are as follow:

1) User requests a list of their inventories and their items.

2) User selects 1 or more items from 1 inventory and requests for them to be sent to another inventory. This is where my TransferService would come in and coordinate the txIn and txOut from the specified inventories, and persist those changes through the repo. Maybe that should be an infrastructure services? That's one thing I'm not clear on.

3) User predefines a set of items he would like to be able to transfer to an inventory regardles of what inventory those items are currently in. TransferService would find where those items currently are and coordinate the rest as use case 2 does.

**EDIT2:** About the repo.transfer
This is actually a constraint/optimization? from the data side, from what I've been told all it does is lookup the item and change the inventory id that it points to. This is because items cannot be in 2 inventories at once. So instead of `repo.update(fromInvInNewState)` and `repo.update(toInvInNewState)` there is `repo.moveChild(toInv, child)` because we don't want to rewrite the entire state of the inventory (all its items that haven't moved, and because the rest of its state is derived from the items that it has at any point), just move some items around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to recap the domain model defined by your scenario.

You said that you are building an Inventory Tracker with the next spec:

- An User has Inventories.
- An Iventory consists of Items.
- An User can transfer Items from one Inventory to another. I guess that both inventories belong to the User as you said that:
  "User requests a list of their inventories and their items. User selects 1 or more items from 1 inventory and requests for them to be sent to another inventory..."

On the other hand, an invariant you pointed out are:

- An Item can be transferred from the Inventory where it already is (InventoryA) to another Inventory (InventoryB) only if InventoryB is not already full. I guess that in case that the Item cannot be transferred it should be kept in the InventoryA.
- If I understood well, an User transfers his Items between his Repositories.

Something like:

```
class TransferItemService {
    public function execute(TransferItemRequest request)
    {
        user = userRepository.findOfId(request.userId());
        user.transferItem(request.itemId(), request.fromInventoryId(), request.toInventoryId()); //Checks invariant -> the given Item is in one of his Inventories, the destination Inventory is owned by him, the destination Inventory is not full and finally transfers the Item
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now, in order to define the Aggregate Root/s I would need to know if my business can deal with eventual consistency. That is, if moving an Item must be done atomically (just one request) or it can take some time (more than one request).

**No Eventual Consistency**

In case business says that Eventual Consistency is not allowed here, if you want to ensure that your domain remains consistent and aligned to the invariant, the User would be the unique AggregateRoot as he is the nexus between his Inventories. In this case, you can face performance problems due to loading all the Inventories along with their Items.

**Eventual Consistency**

In case that you can go with eventual consitency, you can have the next Aggregate Roots: `User`, `Inventory`, `Item`. So, using the previous code to model the use case of transferring an item:

```
class TransferItemService {
    public function execute(TransferItemRequest request)
    {
        user = userRepository.findOfId(request.userId());
        user.transferItem(request.itemId(), request.fromInventoryId(), request.toInventoryId()); //Checks invariant -> the given Item is in one of his Inventories, the destination Inventory is owned by him, the destination Inventory is not full and finally transfers the Item
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

In this case, the `transferItem` method would look like:

```
class User {
  private string id;
  private List<UserInventory> inventories;

  public function transferItem(itemId, fromInventoryId, toInventoryId)
  {
    fromUserInventory = this.inventories.get(fromInventoryId);
    if(!fromUserInventory) throw new InventoryNotBelongToUser(fromInventoryId, this.id);

    toUserInventory = this.inventories.get(toInventoryId);
    if(!toUserInventory) throw new InventoryNotBelongToUser(toInventoryId, this.id);

    toUserInventory.addItem(itemId);
    fromUserInventory.deletetItem(itemId);
  }
}

class UserInventory {
  private String identifier;
  private int capacity;

  public function deleteItem(userId, itemId)
  {
      this.capacity--;
      DomainEventPublisher.publish(new ItemWasDeleted(this.identifier, itemId));

  }

  public function addItem(userId, itemId)
  {
    if(this.capacity >= MAX_CAPACITY) {
      throw new InventoryCapacityAlreadyFull(this.identifier);
    }
    this.capacity++;

    DomainEventPublisher.publish(new ItemWasAdded(this.identifier, itemId));
  }
}
```

Notice that `UserInventory` is not the `Inventory` Aggregate Root, it is just a VO with an identifier reference and the current capacity of the actual `Inventory`.

Now, you can have a Listener that asynchonously updates each Inventory:

```
class ItemWasRemovedListener()
{
  public function handleEvent(event)
  {
    removeItemFromInventoryService.execute(event.inventoryId(), event.itemId());
  }
}

class ItemWasAddedListener()
{
  public function handleEvent(event)
  {
    addItemToInventoryService.execute(event.inventoryId(), event.itemId());
  }
}
```

Unless I have made a mistake I think we have satisfied all our invariant, we have just modified one Aggregate Root per Request and we don't need to load all our Items to perform an operation on an Inventory.

If you see something wrong please let me know :D.

Comment: Just finished Evans and Vernon's books. I agree with your response, but another questioned surfaced. I agree with User being the AR and handling the invariants of the Inventories instances. The problem now is that some inventories are shared between users. Say, a team has a common inventory and then each member has their own inventory. So the flow is User1 transfers his item to the common inventory, and the User2 retrieves the item from the common inventory. Can entity instance be shared across aggregates like that? Or does this mean I should model a team? Who hosts the transfer() method?

Comment: Maybe pass in the common inventory to the user transfer method?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing at least one aggregate and trying to replace it with your persistence. Talk to your domain expert, find out *who or what* is doing this transfer. I bet you will not hear that this is done by "a repository" or "a database". This *something* will be your aggregate and it will probably have this `Transfer` method. This call would also encapsulate the login from `transferIn` and `transferOut` since this seems to be a transactional process and you are doing it in three different places. Remember that your transaction boundaries is your aggregate. Not your repository.

Comment: Well it's the inventories that do the transferring. That's why they have the transfer in and out methods. I use a service as a coordinator so I don't have to call the inventory repo for persistence within the inventory entity. There's no business logic in the repo transfer method.
EDIT: Thanks for your response, I've added some use case or workflow details to my question, hopefully they help.

Comment: I cannot see it since there is no code. `Transfer` for me sounds like a business term and `Repository.Transfer(item, item)` looks like a technical object doing the business operation. I might be wrong but this is how it looks like. Still, you have two aggregates involved in one transaction, which smells.

Comment: I have added some details to the question. And the repo does only deal with persistence. It is actually a constraint from the data side, from what I've been told all it does is lookup the item and change the inventory id that it points to. So really the method is repo.txChildTo(dest, item)

Comment: I see your point about 2 aggregates involved in 1 transaction. If I was to point at a potential aggregate to include inventory I'd say the user itself. But then my user class would become convoluted as users have a few other entities they would have to maintain invariants for. I could also propose a SuperInventory object that would hold all the inventories and transfer between them, but I think that'd end up being the same logic that the service does: get item out of one and put it in another while having those inventories do their validation. Plus this superInventory does not really exist.